# Testing the difference between marginal effects calculated across factors

Tags: r, marginal-effects

I'm trying to test the difference between two marginal effects. I can get R to calculate the effects, but I can't find any resource explaining how to test their difference.

I've looked in the margins documentations and other marginal effects packages but have not been able to find something that tests the difference.

```r
data("mtcars")

mod<-lm(mpg~as.factor(am)*disp,data=mtcars)

(marg<-margins(model = mod,at = list(am = c("0","1"))))
 at(am)     disp    am1
      0 -0.02758 0.4518
      1 -0.05904 0.4518
summary(marg)
 factor     am     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
    am1 1.0000  0.4518 1.3915  0.3247 0.7454 -2.2755  3.1791
    am1 2.0000  0.4518 1.3915  0.3247 0.7454 -2.2755  3.1791
   disp 1.0000 -0.0276 0.0062 -4.4354 0.0000 -0.0398 -0.0154
   disp 2.0000 -0.0590 0.0096 -6.1353 0.0000 -0.0779 -0.0402
```

I want to produce a test that decides whether or not the marginal effects in each row of marg are significantly different; i.e., that the slopes in the marginal effects plots are different. This appears to be true because the confidence intervals do not overlap -- indicating that the effect of displacement is different for am=0 vs am=1.

We discuss in the comments below that we can test contrasts using emmeans, but that is a test of the average response across am=0 and am=1.

```r
emm<-emmeans(mod,~ as.factor(am)*disp)
emm
 am disp emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
  0  231   18.8 0.763 28     17.2     20.4
  1  231   19.2 1.164 28     16.9     21.6
cont<-contrast(emm,list(`(0-1)`=c(1,-1)))
cont
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 (0-1)      -0.452 1.39 28 -0.325  0.7479
```

Here the p-value is large indicating that average response when am=0 is not significantly different than when am=1.

Is it reasonable to do this (like testing the difference of two means)?

```r
smarg<-summary(marg)
(z=as.numeric((smarg$AME[3]-smarg$AME[4])/sqrt(smarg$SE[3]^2+smarg$SE[4]^2)))
[1] 2.745
2*pnorm(-abs(z))
[1] 0.006044
```

This p-value appears to agree with the analysis of non overlapping confidence intervals.

Comment: Please, please do not use overlapping confidence intervals to compare means. It is inappropriate. Means have different standard errors than differences of means, and they don’t jibe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, it can be answered using `emtrends`:

```
library(emmeans)

emt = emtrends(mod, "am", var = "disp")

emt  # display the estimated slopes

## am disp.trend      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  0    -0.0276 0.00622 28  -0.0403  -0.0148
##  1    -0.0590 0.00962 28  -0.0787  -0.0393
##
## Confidence level used: 0.95 

pairs(emt) # test the difference of slopes

## contrast estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
## 0 - 1      0.0315 0.0115 28 2.745   0.0104
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question of "Are the slopes statistically different, indicating that the effect of displacement is different for am=0 vs am=1?" question, you can get the p-value associated with the comparison directly from the summary of the lm() fit.

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) * disp, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6056 -2.1022 -0.8681  2.2894  5.2315 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         25.157064   1.925053  13.068 1.94e-13 ***
as.factor(am)1       7.709073   2.502677   3.080  0.00460 ** 
disp                -0.027584   0.006219  -4.435  0.00013 ***
as.factor(am)1:disp -0.031455   0.011457  -2.745  0.01044 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.907 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7899,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7674 
F-statistic: 35.09 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.27e-09
```

Notice that the p-value for the `as.factor(am)1:disp` term is 0.01044, which matches the output from `pairs(emt)` in Russ Lenth's answer.

(posting as an answer because insufficient reputation to post as a comment, yet)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but probably you're looking at contrasts or pairwise comparisons of marginal effects? You can do this using the **emmeans** package:

```r
library(margins)
library(emmeans)
library(magrittr)

data("mtcars")
mod <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am) * disp, data = mtcars)

marg <- margins(model = mod, at = list(am = c("0", "1")))
marg
#> Average marginal effects at specified values
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) * disp, data = mtcars)
#>  at(am)     disp    am1
#>       0 -0.02758 0.4518
#>       1 -0.05904 0.4518

emmeans(mod, c("am", "disp")) %>% 
  contrast(method = "pairwise")
#>  contrast                    estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0,230.721875 - 1,230.721875   -0.452 1.39 28 -0.325  0.7479

emmeans(mod, c("am", "disp")) %>% 
  contrast()
#>  contrast            estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0,230.721875 effect   -0.226 0.696 28 -0.325  0.7479 
#>  1,230.721875 effect    0.226 0.696 28  0.325  0.7479 
#> 
#> P value adjustment: fdr method for 2 tests
```

Or simply use `summary()`:

```r
library(margins)

data("mtcars")
mod <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am) * disp, data = mtcars)

marg <- margins(model = mod, at = list(am = c("0", "1")))
marg
#> Average marginal effects at specified values
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) * disp, data = mtcars)
#>  at(am)     disp    am1
#>       0 -0.02758 0.4518
#>       1 -0.05904 0.4518

summary(marg)
#>  factor     am     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
#>     am1 1.0000  0.4518 1.3915  0.3247 0.7454 -2.2755  3.1791
#>     am1 2.0000  0.4518 1.3915  0.3247 0.7454 -2.2755  3.1791
#>    disp 1.0000 -0.0276 0.0062 -4.4354 0.0000 -0.0398 -0.0154
#>    disp 2.0000 -0.0590 0.0096 -6.1353 0.0000 -0.0779 -0.0402
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I got to the summary(marg) part, but I want to show that disp(at am=0) - disp (at am=1) is significantly different than 0. Here, looking at the confidence intervals, this appears to be true but I don't know how to ask R to do the test.

Comment: Yes, this is what emmeans does (see my example above). See also [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html).

Comment: Doesn't that answer a different question? For example, doesn't emmeans tell us the average response is 0.32 larger for am=1 (versus am=0)? This doesn't tell us that the slope of the marginal effects plots are different, or does it?

Comment: I've added more code and output above (in the original post) to clarify what I mean.